# Error uncaught in promise: time.split is not a function in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

The error which I am receiving in the console is as follows :-

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: time.split is not a function
TypeError: time.split is not a function
    at Function.parseTime (time-adapter.ts:16)
    at Function.formatTime (time-adapter.ts:27)
    at TimepickerDirective.set (ngx-timepicker.directive.ts:88)
    at TimepickerDirective.writeValue (ngx-timepicker.directive.ts:159)
    at shared.ts:114
    at model.ts:1091
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.setValue (model.ts:1090)
    at ng_model.ts:338
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:386)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:832)
    at zone.js:898
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27424)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:507)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671)
```

I am using angular 10 and node version 12. How to avoid this error? Is this error related to NgxMaterialTimepickerModule?

In the .html file I have :-

```
*<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder}}" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="datePart" (ngModelChange)="datePartChange($event)"/>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field><br/>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{timePlaceHolder}}" [format]="timeFormat"  readonly [(ngModel)]="timePart" (ngModelChange)="timePartChange($event)" [ngxTimepicker]="timepicker"/>
    <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="timepicker"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-material-timepicker [minutesGap]="minutesGap" #timepicker></ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>*
```

Comment: What's time variable?

Comment: time is a string in time-adapter.ts file.

Comment: Well it probably isn't, since it `time.split` is not a function..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are providing a string. Had the same error but, in my case, I was using reactive forms and providing an array instead of a string when updating the form:

```
this.form.setValue({
    time: ['06:00 AM'],
)};
```

So I had to change the above to:

```
this.form.setValue({
    time: '06:00 AM',
)};
```